# How to retrieve the full directory path from Lucene.Net.Store.Directory?

Tags: lucene.net

I'm trying to access the directory path from Lucene.Net.Store.Directory, and I can't find any properties where it exists. If I call ToString() I see the path along with the type name, etc. and I would just like the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Lucene.Net.Store.Directory` class does not have a `DirectoryInfo` (or `Directory`) property since its a abstract class and does not directly access the file system, with even some derived classes not using the file system at all to store the index (take for instance the `RAMDirectory`).

However, for the `Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory` directory class, you can access the `Directory` property, type `DirectoryInfo` and then its `FullName` property to get the absolute directory path in use,

```
var directoryInfo = simpleFSDirectory.Directory;
var fullPath = directoryInfo.FullName;
```